# Windows Phone 8 having a 'read more'-button in description

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8 app in which i want to show a title and description. my description is very big so i want to show some characters first with a read more button and then when the user clicks that button, he will be able to see the remaining description. how can i achieve this and what are the guidelines for creating read more button in Window Phone 8? How can i achieve this in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by switching the Description text:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private string _shortText;
  private string _fullText;
  private bool _showFullText;

  public string Text { 
    get
    {
      if (_showFullText) 
        return _fullText;
      else 
        return _shortText;
    }
  } 
  public void Switch() {
    _showFullText = !_showFullText;
    OnPropertyChanged("Text");
  }
}
```

Then you put a TextWrapping TextBlock for {Binding Text} and an underlined TextBlock where you call the Switch Method in the Tap event.